# Anchor in AMP page with with href="#" and on="tap.nav-about.toggleClass(class='active')" causes page to reload with # in URL

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to do something like this...

```
<div id="warning-message">Warning...</div>
<button on="tap:warning-message.toggleClass(class='active')">Cool, thanks!</button>
```

But with an anchor tag?

```
<div id="warning-message">Warning...</div>
<a href="#" on="tap:warning-message.toggleClass(class='active')">Cool, thanks!</a>
```

The page jumps back to the top of the page with # in the URL. Does AMP support some sort of prevent default option?

Answer (score 0):

No does not support prevent default option, but in your case a hack work

```
<div id="warning-message">Warning...</div>
<a href="#warning-message" on="tap:warning-message.toggleClass(class='active')">Cool, thanks!</a>
```

Try like this